# .NET Regular expression for time 24 hr format

Tags: vb.net, regex

Can I please have a regular expression in .NET, which will allow only 24 hr time format in the textbox.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regular Expressions: Time hh:mm validation 24 hours format:

```
([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)
```

If you need seconds too:

```
([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)(:([0-5]\d))?
```

**Edit**:
To prevent trailing AM/PM, partial match can't be allowed or you have to put the expression between ^ and $.

```
^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)(:([0-5]\d))?$
```

Comment: @Manoj: isn't the point with 24 hour clock that you omit AM/PM?

Comment: @Fredrik @eed3si9n,  I think Manoj may be saying that this allows AM/PM and shouldn't.  It needs anchors to avoid this.  ie At the moment it would match 23:15 AM

Comment: @Ash I see. If that's the case, I'll put the expression between ^ and $ like others are suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$
```

It's 24 hour time with optional seconds.  [(Source)](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5)

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`DatePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(VS.95).aspx) or [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) depending upon if you're using WPF or Winforms? This might be a better UE anyways.

Comment: I read your links, but was not able to understand completely. can I have code example using vb.net. How can I use it in my vb.net code. Thanks!

Comment: Just google around. I'm sure you can find some examples. Basically, the point I was trying to make is that you should probably use one of the pre-built date controls if you really want the user to input date/time info.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, rather than go the validation route I would use a control like a datetime picker for the following reasons:

- Zero validation is required. In fact the only validation you'd do would be business rules validation e.g. Order date cannot be later than today, etc
- Easier on the user -- you don't have to tell the user to key in the time in 24 hour format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360801/net-regular-expression-for-time-24-hr-format/1360842#1360842

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [The Regulator](http://www.osherove.com/tools) for next time when you need a regular expression, its a great tool for designing your expressions.