# SQL server reporting Validate parameter is in correct format

Tags: validation, reportingservices-2005

On my reporting application which is developed using SSRS 2005, I have a parameter of type string which accepts time. the time should be in the format "HH:mm:ss" How can I check if the input string is of correct format?

I tried to do the following
IsDate(TimeValue(parametr!stime.Value))
This returns true as long as the value is within range. But if the value is 24:00:00 or a wrong value then an exception is thrown.

I also tried to create a function in the report code as follows:

```
Public Function CheckNum(sNum as String) as Boolean
Dim msg as String
msg = ""
Try
If IsDate(TimeValue(sNum))=1 Then
Return True
Else
msg="Parameter must be a number"
End If
Catch ex as Exception
Return False
End Try
If msg <> "" Then 
MsgBox(msg, 16, "Parameter Validation Error")
Err.Raise(6,Report) 'Raise an overflow
End If
End Function
```

And when I input a value 24:00:00 I still get an error

" The  conversion of a char type to datetime data type resulted in an out of range date time value"
How can I handle the exception so that I don't the error?

EDIT:

```
public Function CheckNum(sNum as String) as Boolean

Dim REGEX_TIME = "^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$"       
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(sNum, REGEX_TIME) Then
Return True
Else
Return False
End If
End Function
```

Then I assigned a parameter(validateTime) value as =Code.CheckNum(Parameters!sTime.Value)

But the value of the parameter is always true. When I specify a value greater than 23, I still see the error. Please see the image [image: Error when time is invalid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using IsDate function, use VB.NET regular expressions. SSRS allows full use of .NET functions.
See an example of [time regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360801/net-regular-expression-for-time-24-hr-format).
[A good tutorial on regex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial).

Example Code Console Application

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim REGEX_TIME = "^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$"
        Dim InputList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        InputList.Add("25:00:21")
        InputList.Add("22:00:21")
        InputList.Add("AA:00:21")
        InputList.Add("17:21:02")
        For Each input As String In InputList
            If Regex.IsMatch(input, REGEX_TIME) Then
                Console.WriteLine("TIME " + input + " IS OK")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("TIME " + input + " IS NOT OK")
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output is :

```
TIME 25:00:21 IS NOT OK
TIME 22:00:21 IS OK
TIME AA:00:21 IS NOT OK
TIME 17:21:02 IS OK
```

Comment: I get an eroor BC30465: 'Imports' statements must precede any declarations. But i do not have any declarations in my code before the Imports statement.

Comment: Example code is console application. You can not copy paste that code as it is. SSRS changes your code as it interprets (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/478155/cannot-use-imports-statement-in-reportviewer-control-custom-code). Change your code so that instead of import you use full name of Regex class like  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch

Comment: Last error is different. You are trying to create a INVALID date. There is no time as 26:00:00. Try 23:59:59.

Comment: Ofcourse 23:59:59 will be true. But I want to capture the wrong input and show an error, and prevent the report from being generated.

Comment: You are asking a different question. How to raise a message for invalid input. See this article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/66259/. It is for InvalidNum but you already have control for date.

Comment: I dont wish to display MessageBox,instead I have a textbox on report which will display the error. And I do not wish to use the control for date as I only need the Time and not the date part. So even though the input is wrong the report still continues to process, despite the validateTime parameter value being False.

Comment: You are using SSRS default GUI. If such an option exists , I do not know it. Default GUI's options are not very powerful. I always used asp.net or windows forms page to call reports whenever i need this type of complex processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can capture a `InvalidCastException`.