# How to check if the input field is in the Time format in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, time-format

I'm currently making an enrollment system and I want something like a [Required] (attribute?) to check if the input string is in the proper time format (18:00, 20:00, 1:00, etc.), how do I do that? Is there a function for it or will it manually have to be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegularExpressionAttribute` with the following regex:

```
^([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wnST77TWSl8VyyxA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RegularExpression` as validation attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$", ErrorMessage = "invalid date format")]
```

The regex was found here: [.NET Regular expression for time 24 hr format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360801/net-regular-expression-for-time-24-hr-format)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks, corrected it using your regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a method like this:

```
public bool IsValidTime(string time)
{
    DateTime dummyDate;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(time, new[] { "HH:mm", "H:mm" }, 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out dummyDate);
}
```

This method validates 24 hour clock formats, with 1 or 2 digit hour numbers.

It gives the following results with supplied inputs:

```
"00:00"  => true
"20:00"  => true
"26:00"  => false
"1:00"   => true
"10:5"   => false
```

Answer (score 0):

use TimeSpan.TryParse Converts the string representation of a time interval to its TimeSpan equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If I recall correctly, it shouldn't throw an error when the string "12345" is passed, as it assumes that's the amount of seconds then. If I remember this correctly (looking for confirmation now)